# Bash - Echo is splitting my string result

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command, teamcity, echo

I have the following:

```
VERSION=$(curl -Is https://qa.me.com.br | sed -n '/^x-powered-by:/Ip' | sed '/x-powered-by:/I s/x-powered-by: //Ig')
```

Expected variable result (but it has one more character that broke my result):

> MEWeb - QA - 267_4_2548

After, I'm showing by the following:

```
echo "##teamcity[progressMessage 'Version is $VERSION']"
```

Expected (without '*'):

> *##teamcity[progressMessage 'Version is MEWeb - QA - 267_4_2548']

Actual:

> ']##teamcity[progressMessage 'Version is MEWeb - QA - 267_4_2548

I don't know what is breaking my result.
Thanks for help and sorry for my english!

Comment: CR symbol at the end of $VERSION variable...

Comment: If you do `printf '<%q>\n' "$VERSION"`, you'll see a `\r` (carriage return) at the end.

Comment: Uh, on second thought, that dupe says "carriage return", but is actually about "linefeed" - nevertheless, the answers there cover removing a carriage return as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
| tr -d '\r'
```

to the end of the `curl` command (just before the ")").

Answer (score 0):

The response has a carriage return.
When you get the VERSION, put it in a file.
echo $VERSION > test.txt

Now, to see the hidden characters, use:
cat -v test.txt

You'll see:
MEWeb - QA - 267_4_2548**^M**

You need to handle that character, which is causing the trouble.